# How to minimize all open windows except my program?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio

I want my program to be the only program showing, is there a way to do that?

I suppose by running something like

```
WindowState = ALL.Minimized;
```

**Update**

I made a Script like this

```
Set shell = wscript.CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Shell.MinimizeAll
```

Named it Mini.vbs
Then i used this code in Visual Studio

```
   {
InitializeComponent();
TopMost = true;
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("c:/mini.vbs");
        }
```

It works, but its not the best solution .

Comment: You need to at least specify a programming language.

Comment: What a coincidence! My program wants to do the exact same thing. How will that work out when they both run on the same machine?

Comment: Bad idea, but you could call the shell api's ToggleDesktop() then show your app.

Comment: Why is i a bad idea?

Comment: [What if two programs did this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply  set the `TopMost` property to `True` on the creation of the form.

```
public Form1()
{
 InitializeComponent();         
 this.TopMost = true;
}
```

Goodluck.

Comment: No, this just make you program "alaways on top". But it will not minimaze all the other windows.